# UIDatePicker value does not match displayed date

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I encounter a weird issue if I set the maximum date of a UIDatePicker whenever I change the day on the UI, the value is always day - 1
I am doing something wrong ?

```
class DateField: UITextField {

    private let datePicker = UIDatePicker()


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date
        datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "updateBirthdate", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        inputView = datePicker
        // inputAccessoryView stuff
    }


    func updateBirthdate() {
        text = NSDateFormatter.myFormatter().stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    }
}

extension NSDateFormatter {

    class func myFormatter() -> NSDateFormatter {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }
}
```

Comment: I was running into a similar issue where the month displayed, and the month given by the UIDatePicker's DateField did not match. This is not the simple timezone day off by one error that it appears to be. Some funky stuff happens when the timezone is incorrect on the UIDatePicker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Time zone of your `UIDatePicker` is most likely different from the time zone of `myFormatter()` - you can set time zone for `UIDatePicker` with

```
datePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
```